# java - slow calculation processing

Tags: java, arrays

I try to run this, but it is very slow. Takes ages till it processes and finishes the calculating. Is there anyways I could improve it or make it work faster and more efficiently?

```
int n = 25;
int len = (int) Math.pow(2, n);
String[][] BinaryNumbers = new String[len][];
int[] DummyArray = new int[n];
int[][] BinaryNumbersInt = new int[len][];

for (int count = 0; count < len; count++) {
    BinaryNumbers[count] = String.format("%" + n + "s",
                                    Integer.toBinaryString(count)).replace((" "), ("0"))
                                .split("");

    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
        DummyArray[i] = Integer.parseInt(BinaryNumbers[count][i]);
    }

    BinaryNumbersInt[count] = Arrays.copyOf(DummyArray, DummyArray.length);
}
```

thanks!

Comment: it works just too slow

Comment: What is it actually supposed to do?

Comment: It will take ages to do 2^25 things, especially if you are allocating (and retaining) memory for each.

Comment: I suggest deleting this question, and instead posting on the Code Review site.  Also, be certain to add a problem statement which explains what your code does.

Comment: Please read `String.format(...)` doc.

Comment: By the way your `for` into `for` loop end by  25 * 25^2 = 2.220446e+36 loop before it end... Maybe this is why it take ages... Just saying.

Comment: There is a lot of things that seem completely useless in your code.

Comment: Do you really need `BinaryNumbers`?

Comment: @MauricePerry indeed. The value of `BinaryNumbersInt[i][j]` can just be calculated as `(i & (1 << j)) != 0 ? 1 : 0`, or something like that.

Comment: And DummyArray is copied at each iteration...

Comment: Step back and include information about the problem you are trying to solve with "code".

Comment: Yeah I need BinaryNumbersInt but not for this stage, only posted the calculation and loops not how I a going to use them..

Answer (score 0):

You're doing a lot of useless string manipulation. Try something like this:

```
for (int count = 0; count < len; count++) {
    int[] DummyArray = new int[n];
    int x = count;
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
        DummyArray[n-i-1] = x & 1;
        x >>= 1;
    }

    BinaryNumbersInt[count] = DummyArray;
}
```

Comment: @o6707448 well, perhaps you don't need to build the array at all: you could just compute the value of `BinaryNumbersInt[count]` when needed.